# Insert generic object into array swift

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

I'd like to create an extension function on 'Array' that inserts an array at the index provided.

```
mutating func insert<T>( array: [T], atIndex index: Int ) {
    var floatingIndex = index
    for (index, value) in enumerate(array) {
        self.insert(value, atIndex: floatingIndex)
        floatingIndex++
    }
}
```

Something like this, but I get an error saying I can't invoke 'insert(...)' with an argument of type (T, atIndex: Int).

Is there a way I can insert a generic into an array?

Comment: `extension Array {
    mutating func insert( array: Array<T>, atIndex index: Int ) {
        var floatingIndex = index
        
        for value in array {
            self.insert(value, atIndex: floatingIndex)
            floatingIndex++
        }
    }
}`

Comment: As explained in the answer to the duplicate, you just have to remove the `<T>` from the method signature, then it compiles and works as expected. – Note that you can achieve the same with `array.replaceRange(insertIndex ..< insertIndex, with: otherArray)`.